# session id in the user table in database - Should i use asp.net session id or create one through sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, oracle10g, security

I am designing an in house application in asp.net 4.0 and have to use the window authentication.  Database and application both are on different servers.

**Environment**

Asp.net 4.0, Vb.net 4.0, Oracle 10g, window server 2003 and IIS 6.0

**Scenario**

When user lands on the first page, system will assign a session id for this user and this id will be saved in the database in the user table under LAST_SESSION_ID column. So every time he access the application (or on new session) system will overwrite this LAST_SESSION_ID column.  I will be keeping the session id in the session variable and pass it to oracle store procedure on every DML transaction and will compare this id with the value in LAST_SESSION_ID column, if they are same then it means user’s session is still active.

**Questions**

> - I like to know if I should create the unique session id in the oracle database (through sequence) or use the one generated by asp.net session ‘HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID’? To get the unique asp.net session id I would have to set the webconfig file with the following settings and I don’t know if it is a good idea as I haven’t used this technique before.

> - Is there any better solution to above scenario? For an example the system I am designing is for 200-300 users (Timesheet APP) and this is an in house application so security is not a big concern. Instead of authenticating the session in the store procedure can’t I just check the session before user send the request to database server?

Comment: Using the built in SessionID is a good idea as it provides you exactly what you want. I just didn't get WHY you want to pass it around in database calls "to see if it is active". The Session ID will be only passed in database calls if the user is active, navingating through the pages and making calls. Guess I missed the point.

Comment: in case if user copy and paste the URL of page2 into the browser. He should be accessing this page2 after landing on the Home Page so system can create a unique session id for him.

Comment: Every use that makes a request to your website gets an unique SessionID value. I still don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: 1- For security reasons, I don't want users to access specific pages through copying URL in the browser becuase when they land on the first page system will set the menus according to their access rights (defined in the database tables).

Comment: How would you strat a new session after it expires?

Comment: Looks like that you are trying to reinvent forms authentication. This expiration is called sliding expiration and it is controlled by .NET for you. Look here for a reference -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If this is for security reasons, the answer is you need to check the users access, based on their username as authenticated by the web server, on every request.

Rather than worrying about how they got to page 2, just ask "are they allowed to see page 2".